# React native expo don't connect to socket server just when it's builded

Tags: react-native, socket.io, vps

I'm facing a rather unusual issue! I'm developing a mobile application using React Native Expo, and it connects to a server socket created with Socket.io, which is hosted on a VPS. When I'm using Expo Go during development, everything works perfectly. However, when I build the application and install the APK, the application fails to establish a connection with the VPS server. Interestingly, there are currently no active firewalls on the VPS. The error message I'm receiving is "xhr poll error."

connexion react native expo :

```
let socket = SocketIO(ServerAddress.Socket);

socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
    alert(error);
});
```

it always return xhr poll error

Server Socket :

```
const app = require( "express" )();
const http = require( "http" );
const { Server } = require( "socket.io" );

const options = {};
const httpServer = http.createServer( app );
const io = new Server( httpServer, options );

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

})
```